# SELECT Multiple Columns for Output in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, multiple-columns

I have a table of stock quotes, where I loop through days to calculate a 14day RSI for a ticker:

```
DECLARE @StartingDate smalldatetime
DECLARE @EndingDate smalldatetime
DECLARE @FinalDate smalldatetime
DECLARE @StockID char(15)
DECLARE @DAYS INT
DECLARE @AG FLOAT(4)
DECLARE @AL FLOAT(4)
DECLARE @RS FLOAT(4)


SET @StartingDate = '20180101'
SET @FinalDate='20180405'
--SET @EndingDate = DATEADD(day, 14, @StartingDate);
SET @EndingDate = '20180403'
SET @StockID = 'ACE'
SET @DAYS = 14


WHILE (@EndingDate < @FinalDate)

BEGIN

SET @EndingDate = DATEADD(day, 13, @StartingDate);

    SET @AG =(
                --SELECT SUM([px_close]-[px_open]) 
                SELECT SUM([px_close]-[px_open]) 
                FROM [Coinmarketcap].[dbo].[daily_data]
                WHERE [Ticker] = @STOCKID
                AND ([Date] BETWEEN @StartingDate AND @EndingDate) 
                --AND ([px_close]-[px_open])>0)/@DAYS
                AND ([px_close]-[px_open])>0)/@DAYS

    SET @AL =(
                --SELECT SUM([px_close]-[px_open])
                SELECT SUM([px_close]-[px_open])
                FROM [Coinmarketcap].[dbo].[daily_data]
                WHERE [Ticker] = @STOCKID 
                AND ([Date] BETWEEN @StartingDate AND @EndingDate) 
                AND ([px_close]-[px_open])<0)/@DAYS

    SET @RS = @AG/ABS(@AL)
    SELECT @STOCKID AS [Ticker], @EndingDate AS Date, @AG AS AvGain, @AL AS AvLoss, @RS As RS, 100 - (100/(1+@RS)) RSI

    SET @StartingDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartingDate);

END;
```

My loop produces RSI values for each day as individual outputs:

```
Ticker  Date       AvGain        AvLoss       RS            RSI
ACE     2018-01-14 0.09985857    -0.07670186  1.301906      56.55773

Ticker  Date       AvGain        AvLoss       RS            RSI
ACE     2018-01-15 0.1158097     -0.0737355   1.57061       61.09873

Ticker  Date       AvGain        AvLoss       RS            RSI
ACE     2018-01-16 0.1150289     -0.1010219   1.138653      53.2416
```

How do I combine the output into one table, instead of separate tables for each date?

Comment: I would suggest to define a table variable and insert the results in the loop. At the end / after the loop I would then perform a SLECT * FROM tableVariable.

Comment: By the way: is AL and AG identical??

Comment: Thanks Tyron, I'll try the tableVariable approach.  AL is AvgLoss and AG is AvgGain

Comment: Ah, OK - I missed the `<0` and `>0` in your calculation... Please keep me updated, if the approach worked out for you.

Comment: Tyron, I declared a TableVariable but am having problems setting the parameters for the dates (starting, ending, etc).  How do I set parameters in a Table Variables?

Comment: Please post your updated code. ;-) But: you don't have to SET it - you simply insert into it!  like `INSERT INTO @MyTableVariable SELECT...`